# What is the question asked by workers in departure when they want to know if you are on a connecting flight?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

Airport workers ask you a question to know if you are on a connecting flight but they use a different term for it.

Comment: workers in departure?? What does that even mean??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question belongs on https://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "making a connection"?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for the term **transit passenger**, according to [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/transit-passenger):

> a passenger at an airport who is there to change flights and therefore does not have to go through customs or immigration

The question could be:

> Are you a transit passenger?

Attribution:"Transit Passenger - definition and Synonyms." Transit Passenger (noun) Definition and Synonyms | Macmillan Dictionary. Accessed April 15, 2018. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/transit-passenger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your luggage on (some flight)?